# Can i run custom app instead of Windows desktop?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop

I want to replace default Windows desktop with my own app, written in C# using WPF(I can rewrite it using C/C++), is it possible? I can make any system modifications.

My app is a game launcher, list of games is loaded from server. My app also contain some user profile features.

Comment: You want to rewrite what the Windows Kiosk mode does? Or do you just want a different UI for the same features of the desktop?

Comment: @Ralf, I want to rewrite what Windows desktop does. My app is game launcher, list of games is loaded from server

Comment: Use Kiosk Mode in Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Comment: Game launchers don't need to replace Windows Explorer. Besides, what happens *after* the game ends? Or the user hits Ctrl+Alt+Del ? If you want to force users to only work with your launcher, Windows Kiosk is *exactly* what you need. The [Configure kiosks and digital signs on Windows desktop editions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-methods#summary-of-kiosk-configuration-methods) page explains how this works. The documentation section contains specific examples for UWP and desktop applications

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks, Windows Kiosk is what I search